# Twilio Programmable Video - Starting a video call without the user having to enter a room ID and name

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-video

I'm working with twilio programmable video and I've hit a snag.

My issue with programmable video at the moment is that it requires all users to manually enter a roomID and name. I'd like to send the user a URL with the name and roomID already baked in so they can instantly click and join.

Is this possible?

I know if I hit the `/token?identity=Joe&roomName=JoesRoom` endpoint, it returns a token, but i'm unsure of how I can leverage that to dynamically enter a room without the user still having to manually enter information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using a hidden form and a little bit of JS to pull the data from the query string.

Comment: Had to dig into the MenuBar and Room components but I was able to get it working the way I liked.

Comment: Could you share more details about your solution? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. I'm starting with the sample Twilio react app, but I don't know react and can't figure out where to modify the code.